# PHP - creating HTML + upload form

Tags: html, upload

I am working on my portfolio page and for my gallery I used isotope to filter out images. Here's what I want to achieve:

I want to somehow implement an admin user and everytime I connect to it an upload form should appear in the gallery section. After uploading the image in the correct size, providing a title etc., PHP should append a HTML code to that page to set up the new image.

I have to mention that I cannot use mySQL, so an XML file or a simple text one should do the job for the user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You want somebody to build you a HTML gallery complete with PHP content management?

Comment: If available, use sqlite instead of an xml or plain text storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great foundation would be start off getting used to simple xml, an efficient and minimal data storage technique. You get to grips with the the methods it uses and then you are good to go when saving your data as you mentioned. Here a couple of links that would be helpful:

[SIMPLE XML - PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

[BASIC SIMPLE XML USAGE - PHP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

[QUERYING SIMPLE XML DATA - PHP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I will have a look at the links you provided.

Comment: No worries, comment if you have any queries about the other features you talked about.